# Kafka topic is marked for deletion but not getting deleted in kafka 0.9

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to delete my kafka topic which following command.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <zkserver>:2181 --delete --topic test1
```

My kafka version is 0.9 and I have also set `delete.topic.enable` flag to true. Still when I fire above command my topic is only marked for deletion not actually getting deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an orphan producer process running on that topic which was spawned by my java Kafka producer program. That I eventually came to know when I started a console consumer on the same topic. After manually killing that process I was able to delete the topic.

Comment: Even after deleting the process I am not able to delete the topic can you help me on it. I have also made `delete.topic.enable=true`

Comment: makes sense.. make sure auto.create.topics.enable is set to false as well

Answer (score 1):

logic topic are composed of multiple partition, and each partition may have multiple copy. In a word, your topic are physically distributed in multiple instance.

If any instance is down, your topic deletion will not able to finish.